# Static content is not reloaded with Spring MVC and Boot

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot and AngularJs for building an application. Whenever I make changes to my static content, the changes are not loaded when I run the application. The same old UI is loaded again. I have my static content in src/main/resources/static folder. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: How do you run the application? Using Maven/IDE/...?

Comment: I am using STS and maven.

Comment: So, you (1) Run the application (2) Change the static resource (3) Run the application again and it doesn't change? Or do you expect that the static resources are updated while you're running the application (hot swapping)?